# Aligning elements in <h:panelGrid />

Tags: jsf, alignment

I want to align elements as shown in the following image.
[image]

There are 2 columns. One aligned to left of the parent and another aligned to right.
I don't want to specify anything in px or em. How do I achieve this in `<h:panelGrid />` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS.

```xml
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="column1,column2">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

with

```
.column1 {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}

.column2 {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

#### See also:

- [CSS tutorial](http://www.csstutorial.net/)

Comment: Thanks. That helped. One thing though. Giving width as 50% wont work properly in some browsers, IE for example. I need give 49% to make it to work.

Comment: Did you use the proper doctype?